# Render Mustache PHP template with Doctrine entity model

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, mustache, mustache.php

In my Symfony controller I want to render a Mustache PHP template, with a Doctrine entity:

```
// The Doctrine entity, a dump($user) shows the correct entity
$user = $this->get('x_service')->getUserById($id); 

$templateFile = file_get_contents('.../path/to/file'); // tested, it works
$mustache = new \Mustache_Engine();
$renderedTemplate = $mustache->render($templateFile, array('user' => $user));
```

The template file looks like this:

```
<p>
    User name: {{ user.name }}
</p>
```

But the variable is not put into the template. It only shows the "User name:" string. I also tried without the associative array:

```
$renderedTemplate = $mustache->render($templateFile, $user);

// the template file:

<p>
    User name: {{ name }}
</p>
```

This did not work either.

However, when I put another variable with the associative array, that does shows:

```
$renderedTemplate = $mustache->render($templateFile, array('user' => $user, 'meh' => 'hem'));

// the template file:

<p>
    User name: {{ name }} <- still no output
    Meh: {{ meh }} <- this does give output
</p>
```

Some more information: I just want to render this small mustache template in my controller. For the controller response I'm using Twig. This is because I'm just reusing a front-end Mustache.js template.

**Edit**

As I read [the manual](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php), it should work to give an object in the model:

[image]

Comment: Mustache wants an array, is given an `Entity`. Suggest hydrating to an array, per: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#array-hydration

Comment: For your edit : it won't work if your user properties are not `public`. TWIG calls the getter, I don't know if mustache does it too. try `{{ user.getName }}`

Comment: @LP154 That did the trick. I'm so used to private class variables that I didn't notice. Can you post this as the answer?

Comment: Also, before I was using Mustache,JS, which means the entity is converted to a JSON object in Javascript, in which you can do "user.name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work if your user properties are not public.

Try `{{ user.getName }}`